# Highstock chart not rendering data completely on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am struggling with weird problem with Highstock chart. If I have large number of datapoints and multiple graphs on same page one of the graph is shown with partial data on load.

The datapoints are not more then 18000 (half hourly data).

[image: When graph is loaded first time]

and after user clicks on zoom button or even clicks on 'Inspect Element' in chrome the graph is shown as it should be.

I tried searching on stackoverflow however couldn't find any reason for this behaviour.

[image: After user clicks on zoom buttons]

Any help/pointer is appreciated. (I'm using ASP.NET MVC and data is called from JSON returned from Web API, not that it is relevant but wanted to add all these if useful)

thankx,

Siddhant

Comment: Do you think it could be something in your code that is affecting the chart?

Comment: the code is same for all the charts, The JSON parameters for GET is what keeps changing

Comment: How your json looks like, it is valid / sorted via x ascending?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal json. As you see in second picture, the line is drawn without any problem if I refresh the page/graph (or click on 3m 6m or any button on zoom levels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!! The issue fixes it self when I use latest Highstock.js library. I was using 1.3.6 and latest one is 1.3.9